# Active Record scope chaining, ignore joins, if already joined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have modelled, User has Attendances in an Event.

```
class User
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :events, through: :attendances

class Event
  has_many :attendances
  scope :is_attending, -> { joins(:attendances).where(attendances:{attend_status: Attendance.attend_statuses[:attending] })}

class Attendance
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  enum attend_status: { attending: 0, not_attending: 1}
```

My Question is about scoped queries and best practice.

I have put most of my scope queries on Event.

**I want to get all the events for a specific user where attend_status = 0**

```
user = User.find(...)
user.events.is_attending
```

Logically I would think, this reads the best and makes most sense

However that would give me a double INNER JOIN

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" 
INNER JOIN "attendances" "attendances_events" ON "attendances_events"."event_id" = "events"."id" 
INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "events"."id" = "attendances"."event_id" 
WHERE "attendances"."user_id" = $1 AND "attendances"."attend_status" = 0
```

Obviously this creates duplicates which isn't what I wanted.

So options I know I can do

1) USE MERGE

```
Event
  scope :for_user, -> (user){ joins(:attendances).where(attendances: {user: user})}
```

then call

```
Event.for_user(user).merge(Event.is_attending)
```

which gives me the sql

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "attendances"."event_id" = "events"."id" WHERE "attendances"."user_id" = 59 AND "attendances"."attend_status" = 0
```

This is what I want. 
But this seems terrible syntax and is confusing.

2) USE INCLUDES

If I use includes instead of join, I don't get duplicate join. As it loads events separately and is smart enough to not duplicate.

```
Event
  scope :is_attending, -> { includes(:attendances).where(attendances: {attend_status: Attendance.attend_statuses[:attending] })}
```

However I don't want to eager load.

3) ASSUME Table is already joined outside of scope

Finally I can assume that the table is already joined outside of calling the scope,

```
Event
  scope :is_attending, -> { where(attendances: {attend_status: Attendance.attend_statuses[:attending] })}
```

But this seems kinda silly design to me, and makes this named scope less re-usable.

So my questions

1) What is the best approach to this?
The most logical
`user.events.is_attending` is the one I ideally want to use.

2) Is there a way to tell Active Record to ignore joins if they have already happened?

Answer (score 2):

You may add an association with `is_attending` condition to `User` model:

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  enum attend_status: { attending: 0, not_attending: 1}

  scope :is_attending, -> { where(attend_status: attend_statuses[:attending]) }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :events, through: :attendances

  has_many :attending_events, -> { Attendance.is_attending }, through: :attendances, source: :event
end
```

Now you may receive attending events without duplication of join:

```
u.attending_events

SELECT "events".* FROM "events" 
INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "events"."id" = "attendances"."event_id" 
WHERE "attendances"."user_id" = 1 AND "attendances"."attend_status" = 0  [["user_id", 1], ["attend_status", 0]]
```

This approach has a drawback: you can’t combine conditions. But it makes sense if you are working with status columns. Because this approach reflects logic of relations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something close to your first suggestion, except I would merge a scope directly on your inner model (Attendance).

So instead of:

Event.for_user(user).merge(Event.is_attending)

I would go for:

Event.for_user(user).merge(Attendance.is_attending)

This is a clear syntax. Your is_attending scope does not need to have a join and each class is responsible for knowing how to filter itself.

If you use it often, you can create a a `for_attending_user(user)` scope to hide the merge:

```
class Event
  scope :for_attending_user, -> user { for_user(user).merge(Attendance.is_attending) }
  ...
```